# Module import in Python 2.x.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, python-2.6, python-module

I want to use my previous program as a module. But when I import that program, program runs automatically. I do not want to run program. I just want to import that program in to my new program as a module that I use functions or variables from that module. I tried to add  this line `if __name__ == "__main__"`. But it did not work also. How can I prevent this action?(I am using python2.x.x)

Comment: what does your code look like? modules generally don't run on their own when you import them...

Comment: it just contains three of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code inside the `if __name__ == "__main__"` is executed only when you run directly that programm and is ignored otherwise.
The rest of the code is executed all the time.

The correct way to organize your code is to declare every attribute (function, constant, class...) before the `if __name__ == "__main__"`, and then you put the code that run the program. Here is the structure :

```
# only "passive" code until the __name__=="__main__"

# could be importation...
import sys

# ...global variables
version = 42

# ...or functions
def foo(x):
    print("foo called")

def bar(x):
    print("bar called")
    return x + 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # start the effective code here

    print("program running")
    print("version :", version)
    foo()
    n = bar(2)
    print(n)
```

you could also define a function to call at the end

```
...

def main():
    print("program running")
    print("version :", version)
    foo()
    n = bar(2)
    print(n)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: PS: I used the python3 syntax, the only difference with python2 here concern the `print`: use `print "foo called"` instead of `print("foo called")` to make it work under python2